# Does using a SSL certificate for an API server require a domain?

Tags: api, ssl, server, ssl-certificate

I'm using a React frontend application on a domain with a valid SSL certificate, which makes calls to a Django backend application on a VPS (Ubuntu 20.04, apache2), which doesn't have a domain name registered (instead the calls are being made using the IP of the server). The server doesn't yet have a valid SSL certificate which prevents the React app from receiving the resources. Self-signed won't work since it's then not valid in the browser (I might be wrong here).

**Do I also need to register a domain name for the backend API server for the SSL certificate to be valid or can I just buy an SSL certificate and work from there?**

Comment: Short answer: yes, you need a domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To even get an SSL certificate back from the vendor, you need a fqdn (fully qualified domain name). That information is used to sign and create the certificate request. Your webserver won't even properly encrypt until you have valid signed certificate for the server in question. You can expand the number of hosts that a certificate will serve by buying a wildcard certificate (*.example.com vs specifichost.example.com)

If your back end server is on some cloud or hosted service, you can use self signed certificates but you would have to disable "strictness" in your front end. If you're at any time performing financial transactions this is not advisable.

If you're making axios calls, here's a pretty good article on disabling https strictness (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535).

Your vendor for the VPS might have some helpful information on how to harden up the server.

If this is not how you'll be doing this in production and the setup you describe is for testing only, then probably you want to use the environment to set a variable indicating 'strict' or 'test' and switch your calls accordingly. That way, a relaxed setup will work in test or in your sanbox, but production would use a properly configured host with a valid certificate.